# How to get slider range value and store it in a variable within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, slider

How can you get the range slider to store output as a variable (which will then be set as a a session)

Thanks for the help

*have removed < and > so could display it with code

Below is my code (which doesn't work)

HTML Code:

```
    input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="range"
    Value: span id="value" /span
    Value: span id="outputVar" /span
```

JavaScript Code:

```
    var slider = document.getElementById("range");
    var output = document.getElementById("value");
    var outputVarNo = document.getElementById("outputVar");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
```

Comment: Why do you believe this does not work? Do you see an error?

Comment: Code blocks allow entering full HTML.  Please edit your code to reflect the actual HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add an onChange event to your slider.

```
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
slider.onchange = function(event){
  var output = document.getElementById("outputVar");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;
}
```

The answer provided by [@junvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6951428/junvar) is better for live updates.  Plus, the addEventListener is better IMO than directly using oninput

Answer (score 4):

Your example 'works' in that it does display the range value as you've described. It doesn't update the value because your JS code will execute only once at startup. To execute your code and update the output whenever the range input is changed, use an event listener:

```js
  var slider = document.getElementById("range");
  var output = document.getElementById("value");
  var outputVarNo = document.getElementById("outputVar");

  let update = () => output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.addEventListener('input', update);
  update();
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="range">
Value: <span id="value"></span>
Value: <span id="outputVar"></span>
```